# Why Mapstruct cannot generate fields mapping

Tags: spring-boot, mapping, mapstruct

I'm using mapstruct to  do the mapping between two calsses : Candidate and CandidateDTO .

My mapper interface is like that:

```
@Mapper
public interface CandidateMapper {
    CandidateDTO toCandidateDTO(Optional<CandidateEntity> candidateEntity);
}
```

And the generated source is like that :

```
public class CandidateMapperImpl implements CandidateMapper {
    @Override
    public CandidateDTO toCandidateDTO(Optional<CandidateEntity> candidateEntity) {
        if ( candidateEntity == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        CandidateDTO candidateDTO = new CandidateDTO();
        return candidateDTO;
    }
}
```

My problem here is that when mapping i get all DTO fields null because  the mapping field is not generated.

Any help please.

Answer (score 2):

This is not yet supported out of the box by MapStruct. Have a look at issue [mapstruct/mapstruct#674](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/674) in our issue tracker.

What you can do though is use a default custom method.

```
@Mapper
public interface CandidateMapper {

    default CandidateDTO toCandidateDTO(Optional<CandidateEntity> candidateEntity) {
        return toCandidateDTO(candidateEntity.orElse(null);
    }

    CandidateDTO toCandidateDTO(CandidateEntity candidateEntity);
}
```